# paginating the results of the index action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am strugling with integrating `twitter-bootstrap` with my app and i am having some issues with rendering the results in the index action

Basically what I want to do is to have my objects displayed by rows, each row having 4 elements.

To get an idea, I've managed to do this

```
1 2 3 4    
5 6 7 8
```

But this is 1 row, what i need to achieve is something like this

`1 2 3 4`

`5 6 7 8`

Is there a way to do this(preferably w/o using js) when calling

```
<%= render @kindergartens %>
```

or inside the partial?

Comment: You may be looking for [`.thumbnails`](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#thumbnails) instead of rows (depending on your content). And thumbnails don't need to separate elements in different _rows_.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in_groups_of` method. In your view you will do this:

```
<% @kindergartens.in_groups_of(4) do |grp| %>
  <ul>
  <% grp.each do |item| %>
    <li><%= item.id %></li>
  <% end %> 
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

This will render a separate `ul` for each group of 4. Or you can do table rows or whatever fits your needs.